# Pdf logo and Header adjustment in Visualforce Page

Tags: pdf, renderas

**I have a VF page which shows the logo and header in pdf(dynamic) like this:(by renderAs="pdf")-**

[image]

**but on the next page the "header and logo overlaps" and look like this:-**

[image]

**I am using this part of code on vf page. Can somebody please suggest what can i do 
to fix this issue.**

```
                    <div class="header"><div style="margin-bottom:10px;font-size:16px;font-weight:Bold;">USE - NOT FOR ANY FCRA PERMISSIBLE PURPOSE<br/>
                       <img id="Img1" src="{!$Resource.__MBCRLogo}" style = "height: 50px;"/><br/><br/>
            </div></div>
            <div class="footer">
              <div style="width:100%; height:2px; background:black;"></div>
              <table style = "width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <td width = "35%" left-margin = "10px" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:Bold;">
                    Background Check # {!record.name}
                  </td>
                  <td width = "50%" align = "center" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:Bold;">
                    Report Reproduction Date: {!sCurrentDate}
                  </td>
                  <td width = "20%" align = "center" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:Bold;">
                    <div>Page : <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <div style = "height:30px"></div>
            </div> 


                <table style="width:100%;border: 1px solid black;">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="width:743px;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border:0px none #FFFFFF;background-color:#cccccc;">
                      <apex:outputText escape="false" value="Background Check Details" style="color:#000000;font-size:12pt;font-weight:Bold;"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="ColLabel"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="Background Check Status" /></td>
                    <td class="ColValue"><apex:outputField value="{!record.Client_Case_Status__c}" /></td>
                    <td class="ColLabel"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="Background Check Completed Date" /></td>
                    <td class="ColValue"><apex:outputField value="{!record.Report_Closed_Date__c}" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="ColLabel"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="Full Name" /> </td>
                    <td class="ColValue"><apex:outputField value="{!record.Full_Name__c}" /></td>
                    <td class="ColLabel"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="Background Check Requested" /></td>
                    <td class="ColValue"><apex:outputField value="{!record.Formation_Order_Request_Date__c}" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="ColLabel"><apex:outputText escape="false"   value="Background Check Number" /></td>
                    <td class="ColValue"><apex:outputField value="{!record.name}" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce uses Flying Saucer as its back-end for rendering PDFs. Take a look at this documentation https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_40